# When scroll in listview updated data changed to previous data

Tags: android, listview, adapter

In a list view i have image, text and image contains default image and on the image i have a download button. when list load with download complete , every thing works fine but When i scroll the **list-view** the image just changed to static image.

Comment: Some code would be helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567629/listview-change-to-default-when-keyboard-opens
I have added my code in the shared link , please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in a listview, the views get recycled. As soon as you scroll, your view which goes out of display can get recycled and is reused in another row, thus leading to jumbling of images etc...

You will have to use a ViewHolder pattern in your adapter to handle this. Add all your views to your viewholder object and use them to set the images,text etc... this will stop the effect that you want.

see: https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview for a tutorial

also see: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html    for details from google.

NOTE: If you are downloading images from internet, you will either need a caching mechanism or use Picasso,Fresco... or such libraries to handle the slow convergence to the correct image.

The reason why i am suggesting a library is as follows:

1) when you scroll, the image will again go to network to get downloaded, this meanwhile your static placeholder will show up. It will take while for your image to get downloaded. Also unless you implement your own custom cache mechanism, it will always go to download the image.

2) when you scroll, the thread you spawn for downloading will keep running even if the view is out of display.

3) the libraries i mentioned, handle caching on their own... they cancel requests when your view goes off screen.... they handle garbage collection on their own....

Comment: i donot want to use any library, i want to create it by my self.

Comment: added viewholder pattern but it doesnot solve my problem.

Comment: i have checked the Picasso library , and my understanding is that it display an default image unless image is not completely download.
But i want that when i click on download button in listview then download starts like whatsapp.

Comment: You can use a placeholder image set as image source by default. When you click it, run an asynctask or other such mechanisms and pass the reference of this image view as a weak reference and set it when it downloads...

Comment: can you please elaborate more on how to add place holder image.

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll list your `getView` method of adapter class is firing again. You should check each time if the picture that you want to show was downloaded in `getView` method. If it was not downloaded hold your static image but if you downloaded successfully set that image.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...

    if ("downloaded") {
        imageView.setImage("your image");
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.static_image);
    }
}
```